# Does safari handle temporary redirects (307) to a different domain correctly?

Tags: google-chrome, http, firefox, safari, http-redirect

Safari  does not supply the post form data when I redirect to a different domain.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307 on a **temporary redirect 307** the browser should not change the post request.

**Chrome** , **firefox** preserve the post data no matter the given domain. So they behave according to the above link correctly.

But https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html states

> the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it
>   can be confirmed by the user

So I am even not sure which browsers handle temp redirect correctly here.

Anyway can I get Safari not loose its post data on a 307 redirect?

Comment: I think what counts more is the HTTP server being used here :) Sometimes the trick is done on server-side... So Nginx or Apache ... ?

Answer (score 0):

This could well be a CORS issue, does the server that the 307 points at have Cross Origin Resource Sharing enabled? e.g.  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the response headers.

If not then try enabling CORS on that server and testing.

If that doesn't work, then perhaps look at how you are making the initial POST request, are you using xhr (XMLHttpRequest) or something else? If you are using xhr try making the POST via the Fetch API to see if that works.

There was a [webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=57600) that is marked as fixed but it is super similar to what you are experiencing. It could be that you are hitting the same issue still.

Comment: I think this is not a CORS issue because the form is not send by javascript. It is just a form post. But to be sure I also tried putting Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * on the receiving server and it made no difference. Right now I think that safari is handling the redirect 307 as a 302. And the correct handling of 307 is up to the implementer of the browser